# Binding issues Using XML, need to show multiple videos which are in XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to create a video's Using XML, I need to show all the videos that are in my xml. I tried this but videos are not displaying. For one video its working fine but for multiple its not working

http://jsfiddle.net/x7PxM/7/

Comment: Please deliver the question more prescriptively!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a comma where there should either be nothing or a semi-colon; try the following:

```js
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><video>http://www.youtube.com/embed/mkP0FhPWTlQ</video><video>http://www.youtube.com/embed/mkP0FhPWTlQ</video></channel></rss>";
//                                                                                                                                                        Notice this ^
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $xmldata = $(xmlDoc);

var video = $xmldata.find("video").text();

console.log(video);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x7PxM/6/)

**Update**

[This will do what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/x7PxM/9/).  Note that you cannot alter iframes of a different domain due to security restrictions written into the browser software.  It is not possible to bypass these restrictions.

If your iframe is of the same host, port, etc, you can change the following line:

```
$('#video').append('<iframe width="420" height="315" src="' + $(v).text() + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

To:

```
$('#iVideo').append('<iframe width="420" height="315" src="' + $(v).text() + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

And it should work fine.

Comment: Can you please append it to my iframe by showing the videos on the right side demo window in jsfiddle

Comment: @uii I works fine on my end.  The text is printed in the console, as expected.  It saddens me you wish me to do all the work without figuring out what needs to be done.. but alas.  Anyway, my update will do what you want, just know that you cannot influence iframes of a different domain, per security restrictions written into the browser software.